Connect EtherCAT Device with pysoem
I would like to communicate with an EtherCAT Device. Unfortunately, I can't even open the interface.
This is the Adapter as read out by the code provided:
Adapter 6
\Device\NPF_{1F2BE908-A7E6-4622-BE1B-64E48F18FA6C}
b'Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (11) I219-LM'

Actual Code:
import pysoem

adapters = pysoem.find_adapters()

for i, adapter in enumerate(adapters):
   print('Adapter {}'.format(i))
   print('  {}'.format(adapter.name))
   print('  {}'.format(adapter.desc))

master = pysoem.Master()

master.open("/Device/NPF_{1F2BE908-A7E6-4622-BE1B-64E48F18FA6C}")

if master.config_init() > 0:
   for device in master.slaves:
      print(f'Found Device {device.name}')
else:
   print('no device found')

master.close()

Error:
could not open interface /Device/NPF_{1F2BE908-A7E6-4622-BE1B-64E48F18FA6C}


I encountered the same problem on Windows 10.
What worked out for me is:
master.open('\\Device\\NPF_{1F2BE908-A7E6-4622-BE1B-64E48F18FA6C}')
The \\ is the trick I guess. :)

for nic in pysoem.find_adapters():
    master.open(nic.name)
    # master.open(nic[1]) works too
    if master.config_init() > 0:
        break
    else: master.close()

I wrote it so that it searches all network adapters as it is easier and more compatible with switching PCs.
Or, you can use .name on the i object in the adapter list:
pysoem.find_adapters()[i].name

